# Having trouble using settimer() for MFC application

Tags: c++, timer, mfc

I set up this this code so I can have a timer for a minesweeper game but I can't get it to compile.

```
    void CALLBACK CMineSweeperBoard::clock(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
    if (t_seconds < 59){ t_seconds++; }
    else{
     t_minutes++;
     t_seconds = 0;
    }   
}

void CMineSweeperBoard::timer(void)
{
    MSG msg;

    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) &clock);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

The issue seems to be with the arguments in the set timer function but I can't find out what it is, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The compiler already told you what you did wrong before you added that (TIMERPROC) cast.  Adding the cast just shut it up, it did not make you do it correctly.  Handle the WM_TIMER message instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `SetTimer`, `KillTimer`, and `ON_WM_TIMER()`. See the example at the bottom of this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf.aspx

Don't put a message loop in there <s>`While(GetMessage()...)`</s>

You can start a 1 second timer by calling `SetTimer(1, 1000, NULL);` Then add `ON_WM_TIMER()` to message map, which passes the result to `void CMyWnd::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)` This way you don't need to define your own TimerProc

Or you can supply your own TimerProc, but TimerProc function will have to be declared as **`static`**. This can be inconvenient because the static member functions cannot access member data. It would be easier to use `WM_TIMER` instead.